# How to create a simple VBA macro needed for day to day work?

Tags: excel, vba

Consolidate all the three sheets into a database or excel, there might be some misalignment in column names or data within

1. No of Employees under each supervisor
2. Count of employees under each level
3. Split of employees by region/country
4. Any movement in employee count by month
5. Any metrics on new or old employees

Code I have tried to consolidate the sheets but it didn't work out and also I am new to VBA coding so unable to write the perfect code. Any help to write a simple VBA code to automate the above steps?

Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

totalsheets = Worksheets.Count

For i = 1 To totalsheets
If Worksheets(i).Name <> "MasterSheet" Then

lastrow = Worksheets(i).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row
For j = 2 To lastrow
Worksheets(i).Activate
Worksheets(i).Rows(j).Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets("Mastersheet").Activate
        
Worksheets("Mastersheet").Activate
        
lastrow = Worksheets("Mastersheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row
Worksheets("Mastersheets").Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Select
ActivateSheet.Paste
Next
End If
    
Next
```

Comment: I dont get the point, you should show your worksheets. Because just based on the question i cant help you.

Comment: This code seems to be copying all non blank rows from all sheets and pasting them in the mastersheet one after the other. Is that what you want? Sure there is a lot of room for optimization in this code but other than that, what's the **exact** problem you're having? Is it an error? Is it unwanted behavior?

Comment: I am not able to attach the file. How will I share the excel attachment?

Comment: @StavrosJon I want to consolidate the data of all the worksheets in single worksheet and need the following data in one click of macro (a.) No of Employees under each supervisor (b.) Count of employees under each level (c.) Split of employees by region/country (d.) Any movement in employee count by month e. Any metrics on new or old employees

Comment: @VipinSahu Sure, but what is the problem you're having with the code you posted?

Comment: @StavrosJon Actually the code is giving the desired output what I want. Actually, I want the data to be consolidate from multiple worksheets to single worksheets making sure to check the misalignment in the column name plus the above mentioned queries (a,b,c,d,e)

Comment: Column headers with named: employee_login  job_last_hire_date    reports_to_supervisor_employee_login regulatory_region_code department_org_level_1 department_org_level_2 business_unit_name location_name location_city_name location_country_name company_name job_title_name employee_business_title job_level_name employee_class_name employee_type_name employee_contingent regular_temporary_name

Comment: @StavrosJon *Actually the code is not giving the desired output what I want. Actually, I want the data to be consolidate from multiple worksheets to single worksheets making sure to check the misalignment in the column name plus the above mentioned queries (a,b,c,d,e)